# capistrano v2 not failing / rolling back when custom task fails

Tags: capistrano

i have to compile a custom  c coded binary used by our rails app.
this setup is held in a custom rake file (ourapp.rake, below)
running cap v2 i noticed the make was failing but the deploy didn't "fail".
i since just made the task

```
system "cd #{thedir} && exit 1" # simulate failing of custom task
```

but the deploy:cold doesn't *fail*, the debug output (below) clearly shows make failing

am i missing something? i've tried

- searching for error codes/failing scenario of capistrano - nothing (lots of mentions of trying to run custom scripts on failing)
- system v run v invoke

help appreciated, code below

```
# ourapp.rake

namespace :ourapp do
  desc "Compile and Install Performant Parser"
  task :compile_performant_parser do
    thedir=File.join(Rails.root, 'parser')
    system "cd #{thedir} && make clean && make && make install"
  end # compile

  desc "Compile and Install Compareplans process"
  task :compile_binary do
    thedir=File.join(Rails.root, 'compareplans_process/src')
    #system "cd #{thedir} && make clean && make && make install"
    system "exit 1"
  end # compile

  task :install => [:compile_performant_parser, :compile_binary ] do
    puts "Preparing Ourapp for run"
  end
end
```

additions to deploy.rb

```
 namespace :deploy do
  desc "setup ourapp dependencies, dir, binaries and (later data)"
  task :setup_ourapp do
    run "cd #{current_release} && /usr/bin/env bundle exec rake our app:install RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
  after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:setup_ourapp'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out that capistrano does not exit, so you need to test the error code

[Capistrano run local command exit on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625622/capistrano-run-local-command-exit-on-failure)

and to rollback you need to use a transaction type

[How do I use transactions within custom capistrano tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426079/how-do-i-use-transactions-within-custom-capistrano-tasks)